# Process Builder error : The element has an invalid reference

Tags: process-builder, field-update

I have a process builder on Account that updates values of its child record from Address object.

Field Zip in address need to be updated with concatenate value of Zip_vod__c + '_xxx'.
Formula :

> [Account].Address_vod__c.Zip_vod__c & '_XXX'

But in the formula to set this updated value error the following error occurs :

> 'The element has an invalid reference to
>   "Account.Address_vod__c.Zip_vod__c". '

This formula allows to select field from Account object but not from its child object on which record update is needed. Please let me know if it is at all possible or not.

Please find my Process builder screenshot :
[image]

Comment: You will have to change the field name back, go into the process, remove the field, save, change the field name again, go into the process again, reinstate the formula again, then re-activate the process.

Comment: @TSmith can you be more specific? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be [Account].Address_vod__r.Zip_vod__c?

Comment: @Robin De Bondt, No, this also gives the same error. : The formula expression is invalid: Field Account.Address_vod__r.Zip_vod__c does not exist. Check spelling.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use zip formula = `zip_vod__c & '_XXX'`

As if I can understand correctly both zip and zip_vod__c reside in same Address object which you are trying to update.

Comment: yes, but i cannot update Zip field which is a simple text field to formula field. Thats why i needed Process builder to update that one.

Answer (score 1):

In formulas you can not traverse to child records (Account.Address_vod__c.Zip_vod__c), you can traverse only to parent records.

And by looking at process builder screenshot, I can see Address_vod__c is a child object for Account.